# Improving/ Optimizing Performance Query in MySQL PHP

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I have `invoices`, `invoices_items`, `order`, `order_items`. `Invoices` and `Orders` tables contain around 1 million records. `Invoices_items` and `Orders_items` tables contains more than 2 millions records. Items table contains 200,000 records. Now I want to generate a report based on my filter like customers, item categories and more.

Running on PHP 5.6. MySql 5.7 and Apache2.

```
SELECT
  `si_items`.`item_id`
  , SUM(qty) AS `qty`
  , IFNULL(SUM(selling_price * (qty)), 0) AS `salestotal`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(si.id) AS `siso_id` 
  , MAX(si.date_transaction) AS `date_transaction`
FROM
  `invoice_items` AS `si_items`
  LEFT JOIN `invoice` AS `si`
    ON si.id = si_items.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN `items`
    ON si_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(si.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
  AND (si.approved = 1)
  AND (si.deleted = 0)
  AND (items.deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY `item_id`

     UNION

SELECT
  `so_items`.`item_id`
  , SUM(qty) AS `qty`
  , IFNULL(SUM(selling_price * (qty)), 0) AS `salestotal`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(so.id) AS `soso_id` 
  , MAX(so.date_transaction) AS `date_transaction`
FROM
  `order_items` AS `so_items`
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS `so`
    ON so.id = so_items.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN `items`
    ON so_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(so.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
  AND (so.approved = 1)
  AND (so.deleted = 0)
  AND (items.deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY `item_id`
```

When I executed this query for 50 days, it took *1 minute 20 seconds*.

INDEXES are added in tables.

Invoice and Order Tables:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `approved` (`approved`),
KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `finalised` (`finalised`),
KEY `rp_status` (`rp_status`),
KEY `sales_types_id` (`sales_types_id`),
KEY `account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
KEY `date_transaction` (`date_transaction`)
```

Invoices_items & Order_items

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
KEY `vat_id` (`vat_id`),
KEY `qty` (`qty`),
```

Query image:

[image]

I need to increase performance of this query. How should I proceed?

**Show Create Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_types_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `quote_validity` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `delivery_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_representative_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `account_type_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_exempted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text,
  `finalised` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Not Yet finalised - status=1; Need Approval - status = 2; Approved - status = 3',
  `approved` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `approved_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `default_sales_location_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0-Yes; 1-No',
  `generate_do` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `generate_dn` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `do_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cn_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `rp_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `dm_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `currency_id` char(36),
  `exchange_rate_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `exchange_rate` double DEFAULT '1',
  `date_transaction` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `approved` (`approved`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `cn_status` (`cn_status`),
  KEY `created_user_id` (`created_user_id`),
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `do_status` (`do_status`),
  KEY `finalised` (`finalised`),
  KEY `reference` (`reference`),
  KEY `rp_status` (`rp_status`),
  KEY `sales_types_id` (`sales_types_id`),
  KEY `account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `date_transaction` (`date_transaction`),
  KEY `default_sales_location_id` (`default_sales_location_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `invoice_items` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` double DEFAULT '0',
  `cost_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `list_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `selling_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `unit_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `vat` double DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `special_discount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `price_change_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `remarks` text,
  `vat_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `stock_category_id` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1: Stockable 2: Service',
  `is_giftitem` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1: Gift Item 0: NO Gift',
  `item_type_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `stock_category_id` (`stock_category_id`),
  KEY `item_type_status` (`item_type_status`),
  KEY `vat_id` (`vat_id`),
  KEY `amount` (`amount`),
  KEY `qty` (`qty`),
  KEY `unit_price` (`unit_price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: For a question asking to improve the performance of SQL query it would be wise to add the EXPLAIN output. Besides. it would be *extremely wise* to simplify the query taking out insignificant parts leaving only a code that is having the same performance problem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. added explain query result

Comment: I don't get it. Explain says there are only 100000 rows in invoice_items, and you said there are 2 million. Are 95% of them deleted?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, No. Query has been executed for 6 months.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3):

You use a date format function in the `WHERE` clause.

This function then means that the query cannot use an index on the date column.

Removing the date format function in the `WHERE` clause will improve the performance of the query.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any compound KEY, like `(date_transaction, approved, deleted)`.
Also less indices *can* improve overall speed - though counter-intuitive.
Much this index might not help. In that case reduce the data for the time being.

Experiment with not using parts, i.e. both GROUP_CONCATs: `GROUP_CONCAT(si.id) AS siso_id`

One could offer a zoom-in on the group IDs, for a single group, done later.

One can also consider paging: here it might do to offer pages per *month*, reducing the request per page.

Or create an archive table with query results per month.